# IConfiguration Interface ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I usually am using it and I don't know how exactly how it is working.

As in the start-up class we assign interface to interface, then we use the assigned interface later, even if we can't use the interface directly we shall first implement it to the class and then use the class

```
readonly IConfiguration _Config;

public Startup(IConfiguration Config)
{
    _Config = Config;
}
```

I really get confused with this, does anyone have some clarifications as to what is happening behind the scenes?

Comment: Gets injected by ASP.NET Core when the startup class is invoked.  The configuration gets built from multiple sources, including appsettings.json, environment variables, command line arguments and permutations using specific environments.

Comment: Could you please share more details regarding, what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: the configuration is that a class ? and how can i check it ??

Comment: Please, read the answer, I hope it would enlight you more, if you still have any concern feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You showed example of [dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection). There is something defined like that, internally in *.NET*:

```cs
services.AddScoped<IConfiguration, Configuration>();
```

`services` is `IServiceCollection`. You can write your own `class` and `interface`, then try to add them to dependency injection container like in example above.

Comment: so this means that there is already a class with IConfiguration implementation defined internally in .net ? how can I check this class ??

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/src/System/Configuration/Configuration.cs. *.NET* is open source.

Answer (score 0):

> The configuration is that a class ? and how can i check it ??

Well, its not a class first of all, [IConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) is a [interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface) which only define contracts or signature. IConfiguration actually belongs to [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) namespace, its a extesntion class or you can call abstract class, doesn't have anything in base class. So, you cannot see the class itself.

In addition to this, If you have gone through the IConfiguration interface, you would seen following property there that requires to initialize configuration value while loading the application:

[image]

> As in the start up class we assign interface to interface, then we use
> the assigned interface later, even we can't use interface directly we
> shall first implement it to class then use the class

Yes, right you are, this is how interface works in programming, we cannot call them directly because they are not class and only have the definition/signature not the body or anything. In object oriented design we encourage our applciation to be loosely coupled or no tight coupling within each service or module.

In order to achieve this moto, [dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0) (IOC) comes in as savior where, we tent to pass Interface of that particular service through the constructor to make them less dependent each other. Therefore, you usually pass interface between the construction and assign it on the interface instance as below.

Now back to your confusion, as said earlier, if we now implement the interface into a class we can (you can try), no problem at all, in that scenario, you need to register that class (DI) in startup.cs/program.cs which would require unnecessary code. But we want our configuration less dependent, that's why we are not implementing that over the class.

```
readonly IConfiguration _Config; // Service instace not like class because we cannot use new with interface

public Startup(IConfiguration Config) // Constructor injection of interface
{
    _Config = Config;
}
```

**Note:** `IConfiguration _Config;` which is a Service instance unlike class we cannot use new keyward with interface. On the other hand, `Startup(IConfiguration Config)` is a constructor injection of interface. You can [read more details here in official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration?source=recommendations)

Comment: it is becomming little clear now , but still when we call the startup class we call the constructor which need a class implement IConfiguration interface . how this is happening ? and also when we want to access the properties of any key we use the IConfiguration interface instance _Config which is interface not a class . @md-farid-uddin-kiron

Comment: When we pass IConfiguration interface and assign it to the instance of it we don't need class we can directly access its method inside, but if you want to access that configuration property throughout the application and outside of startup.cs/program.cs class then we need to pass the class like this `var readConfig = builder.Configuration
        .GetSection("MyCustomCredentials")
        .Get<EnvironmentVariableHelperClass>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(readConfig);`. [`Check here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLRxQ.gif)

Comment: that is my point , why it is like that ? what is behind the code to accept data from interface inside startup class but out side startup class you need to build a class with configuration .

Comment: Yes right you are, this is how the configuration has been designed.

Comment: thank you , i think the picture i post make it little clear

Comment: Okay, that's awesome.  Let me know if you need any more assistance on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think it becomes more clear now but still complicated . @md-farid-uddin-kiron @Bartłomiej Stasiak
thank you
[image]

Comment: I disagree that `ConfigurationBuilder` implements `IConfiguration`. It has `Build()`, which returns `ConfigurationRoot`: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/src/ConfigurationBuilder.cs. `ConfigurationRoot` implements `IConfigurationRoot`, which implements `IConfiguration`: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions/src/IConfigurationRoot.cs. Previously i pointed you wrongly to `Configuration`, because authors don't follow naming convention : /

Answer (score 0):

This is done automatically. I assume that you just started a new project

There is a `Program` class where all this begins. Started with this line:

```
CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
```

Notice the method `Build()`. This is a method on interface `IHostBuilder` which has an implementation in the class `HostBuilder`. There is a lot of initialization but besides that, there is a configuration of services that happened internally in the method `InitializeServiceProvider()` and then in `PopulateServiceCollection(...)` where you can find this line:

```
services.AddSingleton(_ => appConfiguration);
```

The `appConfiguration` parameter is the type of `IConfiguration` which is initialized before in the method `InitializeAppConfiguration()` where a new `ConfigurationBuilder` instance is created. The `Build` method is called on `ConfigurationBuilder` for getting `IConfigurationRoot`, but this implements `IConfiguration` so you can assign it to the `_appConfiguration`.

So that's the reason why you are able to resolve `IConfiguration` from the `Startup` class. Because it's already registered in the services.

You can check it here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/src/HostBuilder.cs

The exact class which is passed to `IConfiguration` in `Startup` is this one:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/src/ConfigurationRoot.cs

So, yes, there is a concrete class and constructor called beforehand.